# How to make a private variable in a public method

Tags: java, string, methods, private, public

I have a public method but there is a variable inside that I don't want other classes to access. Could I do that like this?

```
public static void example() {
    private {
        String privateString = "Can I do it like this?";
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need, method local variables are local.

```
public static void example() {
  String privateString = "Can I do it like this?"; // <-- like this
}
```

Or, you could make it a class level variable visible to every method in the same class,

```
private static String privateString = "Can I do it like this?";
```

Comment: Your last comment is a bit ambiguous I think.  I guess you are meaning that the variable should be a class variable.

Comment: @ScaryWombat That is not surprising, English is inherently ambiguous. Edited to try and clarify; but, I meant the variable *could be* a class level variable.

Answer (score 4):

A local variable is scoped to the method (or constructor) that declares it. No other methods can access it. Your problem is a non issue.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `private` is for class scoped variables (and methods).  The method's locally declared variable's scope is restricted to the method only (so it is already kinda private).

Answer (score 1):

variable declared inside method is local,scope of this variable within a body only. so no need to make it as private

```
public void show() {
String x="Hii"; }//<--like this
```

variable x is local to that method. so that no one can access this variable.
we can make it as private in class level also

```
   class Global{

   private String x="hii";
   public static void main(String... n){

   System.out.println("x ="+x);}}
```

we use this variable anywhere inside a class but we cannot access outside the class.